# Handling child window messages with parent window handlers.

Tags: parent

How can I handle all the child window messages with parent window handlers?

Comment: Which system is this question about? Windows and .NET, Unix and X, or something else?

Comment: Vague at best, more details please. And the tagging as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you are talking about .NET Winforms:

```
foreach (Control control in Controls) {
    control.Click += myClickHandler;
}
```

Something similar might work with the super secret system you are using.